# Auto +1 question and answer on copy of code block?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, upvotes

There are a lot of good answers that don't really get the number of upvotes they should. People often come in, copy some code, and leave.

Chances are, if they're copying code from an answer, it was both a good question and a good answer, so why not make that an auto upvote?

If people are worried this would lead to manual upvotes being devalued, we could potentially track the values separately and make these copies worth a fraction of a manual upvote.

This could also be implemented with a dialog prompting for a vote instead if people aren't keen on it being automatic.

Comment: What if they copy the code and it didn't work for them...?

Comment: If no code is copied from one of the answers, do question and answer(s) get an auto-downvote, too?

Comment: At that point they're probably going to go back and try another answer so you could transfer the upvote then

Comment: @JeanneDark - No, because that'd pick up when someone's googled something and landed on a question that isn't actually what they're looking for

Comment: What if I copy code just to run it and see the output to decide if I want to upvote or not?

Comment: @Persistence What if they waste more than 5 minutes on a non-working solution and then can no longer change the vote?

Comment: If a spammer copies the content of an answer to make their spam harder to detect, question and original answer still get the auto-upvotes?

Comment: What if I copy the code but never paste and run it? How will the system know not to upvote then?

Comment: @takendarkk - Then you just revoke your auto upvote

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Just make auto-upvotes permanently mutable

Comment: @JeanneDark - Not sure how that would be harder to detect than any other kind of upvote spam

Comment: I copy code from questions/answers all the time, to see if the claims the OP make are correct before attempting to answer Sometimes I copy it because the code is a completely mess and it needs some formatting. Why should I therefore automatically upvote them?

Comment: In the end, this would mean that "gimme-the-codez" questions are considered the best questions and the best answers are code-only answers? An explanation of why or how something works is not just not helpful, it's maybe even harmful because it may make copy-pasting harder. We'd encourage people to ask and give fish, instead of learning/teaching how to fish.

Comment: @Larnu - Copying from an answer, not from a question

Comment: @JeanneDark - That's a good point tbf

Comment: _“Chances are, if they're copying code from an answer, it was both a good question and a good answer so why not make that an auto upvote?”_ — Yes, _what are_ those chances? I’d say _citation needed_. Code is copied to test and critically examine it, not because the answer and a question of unrelated quality is good. Dialogs, separate vote counters etc. are just noise.

Comment: I often copy a particular section of a post to put in a comment. A lot of times it's to explain why it doesn't work. Why should I play whack-an-upvote in this case?

Comment: The point stands, @Persistence . I fix the formatting in answers too. I check that an answer works as I expect too, as sometimes I look at an answer and think "That doesn't look right. Let me check before I comment/vote."

Comment: Or to copy it to a live playground because the OP did not even bother to do that. Or to edit in/out a stack snippet. How exactly do you propose to account for these cases? This is a high-risk (false positives, complexity, breaking existing working systems) low-reward (no clear benefit over other, less intrusive solutions for promoting rating content more) situation - one which one ideally wants to avoid at all costs

Answer (score 19):

Auto-upvotes in *any* situation is not a good idea. How a user uses their votes is their decision. Besides, if the code doesn't work, why would the user want to upvote?

> There are a lot of good answers that don't really get the number of upvotes they should

Then upvote it yourself! You can't force others to vote on an answer, even if it's really good.